# Modify Haskell nested record by value

Tags: haskell, records, template-haskell, lenses

Say I have a nested structure as follows:

```
data Bar = Bar { _id :: Integer, _bars :: [Bar] }
data Foo = Foo { _bars :: [Bar] }
```

And I have a `Foo` with a bunch of `Bars` with various `id`s:

```
foo = Foo [Bar 1 [Bar 2], Bar 3 [Bar 4, Bar 5]]
```

How do, perhaps using lenses, I modify `foo` such that `Bar 5` becomes `Bar 6`?

I know I use `fclabels` to do something like this:

```
mkLabel ''Foo
mkLabel ''Bar
modify bars (\bars -> ...) foo
```

But bars can be nested infinitely. How do I locate and modify the `Bar` with a specified ID?

Comment: Do you want to update it based on the value of the label or based on the position in this tree

Comment: And what do you expect to happen if there are more than one `Bar 5`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, `lens` can do that. The [`Control.Lens.Plated`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Plated.html) module contains tools for "Scrap Your Boilerplate"-style programming with self-similar structures like your `Bar`. The idea is seductively simple: you explain how to find the immediate children of a node (by writing a `Traversal' a a`) and the library recursively applies that traversal to the whole structure.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens    

data Bar = Bar { _lbl :: Int, _bars :: [Bar] } deriving (Show)

makeLenses ''Bar

instance Plated Bar where
    plate = bars.traverse
```

(If you don't want to implement `plate` yourself, you can derive [`Data`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Data.html#t:Data) and leave the `instance` empty.)

[`transform :: Plated a => (a -> a) -> a -> a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Plated.html#v:transform) takes a function which modifies a single node and applies it to the whole structure.

```
fiveToSix :: Bar -> Bar
fiveToSix = transform go
    where go bar
            | bar^.lbl == 5 = bar & lbl .~ 6
            | otherwise = bar
```

Using the example from your question:

```
ghci> let bars = [Bar 1 [Bar 2 []], Bar 3 [Bar 4 [], Bar 5 []]]
ghci> map fiveToSix bars
[Bar 1 [Bar 2 []], Bar 3 [Bar 4 [], Bar 6 []]]
```

As another example, for funzies, let's use [`cosmos`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Plated.html#v:cosmos) to pull all of the `Bar 5`s out of a `Bar`.

```
fives :: Bar -> [Bar]
fives = toListOf $ cosmos.filtered (views lbl (== 5))
```

Comment: It seems that `transformOn` and `transformOnOf` would allow working directly on the `Foo` value.

Comment: @danidiaz Yep, `transformOn` basically just runs `transform` inside a given lens: `transformOn s g = over s (transform g)`